# Solving a second order 2x2 system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So the method that I know of tackling second order 2x2 systems of differential equations is to reduce it to a first 4x4 system. But once you do so and solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, how does one recover the 2x2 fundamental matrix? Especially when there are only 2 eigenvalues with a multiplicity of 2 and thus 2 4-component eigenvectors?

Here is an example of such an equation:

$$\mathbf{x''} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -5\\ 
2 & -2
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}$$

Comment: @Moo yes I can. I will edit the post to show the example.

Comment: It will also be a good idea to show how far you can go with the example before you run into an issue. It seems like you can get to the form $y'=Ay$ with $y\in \mathbb{R}^4$ just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer just a comment but I think an elaboration of this idea leads to an answer :

Suppose that you have the second order system of differential equations
$$\mathbf{x}''=A\mathbf{x}+B\mathbf{x}',$$then the substitution $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}'$ transforms the system to a first-order system of differential equations,
$$\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{x}''=A\mathbf{x}+B\mathbf{y},$$
Then rewriting in terms the block-matrix, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}'\\\mathbf{y}'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}O&I\\A&B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}\\\mathbf{y}\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $$\mathbf{x}''=\begin{bmatrix}2&-5\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x},$$
Then,
$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}'\\\mathbf{y}'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&|&1&0\\0&0&|&0&1\\-&-&|&-&-\\2&-5&|&0&0\\2&-2&|&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}\\\mathbf{y}\end{bmatrix}$$
It is a linear system of first-order of differential equations.

Comment: The textbook I have, "Elementary differential equations and boundary value problems" does not discuss solving 2nd order systems. It deals exclusively with nxn 1st order systems. Are there any books that go into details about 2nd order systems?

Comment: I don't know a reference. But the method is basically to do order reduction and see if the matrix is diagonalisable. I don't know if you can observe that your problem has 3 votes in favour of closing it, that's because your question doesn't show effort. I suggest you with the suggestion I gave find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the 4*4 matrix and try to write the final solution. If you show no effort in working on your question, most probably the question will be closed even though it is an interesting question.

Comment: Anyway, if you made up the matrix, you chose a very ugly one to begin with. The characteristic polynomial is $p(t)=t^4+6$, which has no nice roots.

Comment: The roots of the characteristic polynomial are: $$\pm \sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{2}}(1+i) \ , \ \pm \sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{2}}(1-i) $$